# Horizontal Pod Autoscaler with the ArangoDB Kubernetes Operator

Tags: kubernetes, arangodb, horizontal-scaling

Would it be possible to use the Kubernetes [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) with the [ArangoDB Kubernetes Operator](https://docs.arangodb.com/devel/Manual/Deployment/Kubernetes/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it would be better if you specify your need in detail, such as what you want to scale, or do you want to scale operator itself or your arango cluster (kind: **arangodeployments**)?

Anyway, as from this [Kubernetes HPA Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) it says:

> The Horizontal Pod Autoscaler automatically scales the number of pods
>   in a replication controller, deployment or replica set based on
>   observed CPU utilization (or, with custom metrics support, on some
>   other application-provided metrics). Note that Horizontal Pod
>   Auto-scaling does not apply to objects that can’t be scaled, for
>   example, DaemonSets.

It means you can only scale **Deployment, ReplicaSet, StatefulSet, or ReplicationController**

**In order to autoscale operator itself follow those steps:**

```
$ kubectl get deploy
NAME                                     DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
arango-deployment-operator               2         2         2            2           19m
arango-deployment-replication-operator   2         2         2            2           19m
```

Then autoscale this deployment via: (Modify auto-scale threshold values and change deployment name according to yours)

```
$ kubectl autoscale deployment arango-deployment-operator --cpu-percent=10 --min=1 --max=10

horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/arango-deployment-operator autoscaled
```

If you are looking for auto-scaling ArangoDb cluster, such as `dbservers` or `coordinators`, it won't be possible out of the box, because those objects are part of `arangodeployments.database.arangodb.com` and this crd is not supported by HPA.

You can scale up and down `dbservers` and `coordinators` manually by changing counts in `arangodeployment` as in mentioned in this [Documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Manual/Deployment/Kubernetes/Scaling.html)

Hope it would be useful for you.